# Running R code from website (without paid hosting)

Tags: html, r, shiny, hosting, interactive

There are many related questions, but all of them are about Shiny R, and that requires paid hosting to be always available (since free options such as shinyapps.io have limits). So I'm wondering whether there is any alternative solution for running R code from a website hosted, for example, at GitHub.

To be more clear, I want to use an R script to interactively display a few plots and some derived information, based on some basic settings given by a user. To give a super simple example:

```
var_from_gui = 7 # input in HTML, user e.g. clicks OK
print(paste("input plus five is:", var_from_gui + 5)) # info displayed on website
plot(c(1, 2, 5) * var_from_gui) # image to be displayed on website
```

Firstly, I assume this is very possible in Shiny R - is that correct?

Secondly, is this possible in another way that allows me to run this via e.g. GitHub pages? (Actually I can also use [this more comprehensive university server](https://zid.univie.ac.at/en/services/web-server/tools-on-web-server/web-server-packages/), but I don't suppose it helps with this case.)

I'm aware of `htmlwidgets` too, but, as far as I understand, that only allows very limited interaction such as filtering, and not things like drawing plots based on user input.

One option I found and seems to fit well is OpenCPU, but what's discouraging is the apparent lack of activity (no recent questions/answers/posts etc.) and hardly any useful tutorials or overviews, which also makes it hard to assess whether it's worth trying.

Comment: Hello @gaspar, you can try AWS free tier (https://aws.amazon.com/free/) and launch an EC2 instance where you can install Shiny Server and R Server.

Comment: thanks that's nice to know, but AWS free tier also has limits; in particular it lasts max 1 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I guess I can answer my own question – though **Marc**'s answer seems also useful in general (and prompted to write my own answer).

In essence, shinyapps.io [worked](https://github.com/gasparl/esdi) for me perfectly fine. For a small and not too often used application the free plan is easily enough. What's more, even in the unlikely case that the website goes down due to excessive usage, R users have the possibility to easily run the Shiny app from their own computer (provided that they have R installed).

And of course, the example given in the question is very possible to implement in Shiny R: typically the code is executed via the `eventReactive` function, and, for the "trigger" button, one can use `actionButton`.

Answer (score 2):

For up to 5 small apps with little traffic you could use the free plan on https://www.shinyapps.io/

- - very easy to deploy, because its a RStudio service

Comment: Yeah but thats what I meant by "limited free" option: they have a "25 Active Hours" cap per month, and while it sounds fair enough I have no idea how much usage that would really mean

Comment: Maybe use the free option and see if it's enough then?

Comment: sure that's what I plan to do. the reason I asked this question is because at the moment I only heard about Shiny R from "hearsay". Before I begin learning it, i want to make sure there aren't any better options (and/or if there is anything else important i should know about deploying shiny R).

Comment: you could also use GCS or AWS and set up an R engine or container, there are always pros and cons , so the best solution always depends on your projects requirements like domain ,traffic, backend -database ,etc. there is no single best solution

Comment: what is the target user base for your app?

Comment: it's a statistical calculator for a specific rare but important study design. at the moment i have no idea how popular it will be, but I'd guess it's not a big user base. for now I'll start with shinyapps.io because shiny seems very easy to learn. I'll add more info to this thread when I'll know more, in the coming months

Comment: you know you can always just host shinapplications locally with shinyApp() function for development use

Answer (score 2):

You can host your R functions on the public [OpenCPU server](https://cloud.opencpu.org), for free.

I have done that for my own applications and it works well. None of the limitations that you listed in your question. Also tried Shiny but, as you mentioned, not flexible enough for what I was trying to achieve.

OpenCPU is really a great tool, although not well supported by the community (not sure why, looking at the great value it brings)

I followed the docs [here](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html) to get it up and running. Setup is a bit tedious but fairly well documented.

Once live, I found this server very reliable - your R functions are continuously available, with very low latency (much faster than a Shiny server from my experience)

You are also asking for "*a solution for running R code from a website hosted, for example, at GitHub*" - OpenCPU does handle CD/CI (Continuous Integration) from your custom GitHub repo through a webhook mechanism.
I also implemented such webhook for my apps, so can confirm it works smoothly. Just follow the well-written provided documentation [here](https://www.opencpu.org/cloud.html).

Comment: I know it's a long time but can You elaborate a bit how to use it with GitHub? I made github account, add webhook with provided documentation at opencpu.org/cloud.html then i add one single file for super simple shiny app with dir: github.com/my_user_name/my_app_name Next i made relase with GitHub... and nothing. There's no mail in my spam folder (as doc said), i cant also localize my app in directory my_user_name.ocpu.io - have no clue what path should go to my app. I'm a simple coder in R, in shinyapps the instructions were for a layman. Regards

Comment: I did follow this same set of instructions. Two things that comes to mind for now: 1) make sure that the specific GitHub repo were your R code lies is public (if private, the webhook call fails - I did try it), and 2) please inspect the system logs of the webhook functionality, which you can easily find in your GitHub setting/dashboard (under webhook), the logs there get updated after each call and are very useful to understand what is happening and hopefully correct it. good luck

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately, I think I will give up further attempts at this solution. From my point of view: the blog and updates do not seem to have been resumed since 2018. There is no support or many examples that would currently run without errors - what is left reports deficiencies, e.g. ggplot2 and other libraries. At the level of the system logs of the webhook itself, the feedback is laconic and it is not clear what exactly it concerns... and many others. Thank you for the information about the fact that the repository must be public, I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: As a potential new direction, "WebR" - R for the browser and Node.js using WebAssembly, is now out. Here: https://docs.r-wasm.org/webr/latest/
I have not experimented with it yet but it looks like a very promising alternative, especially server-side (Node.js)